# HorizontalScrollView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, horizontal-scrolling

I'm new to Android. I need to implement a horizontalScrollView half screen in ViewPager. The viewPager works well, it swipes. I have inserted the horizontalscrollview in detail_fragement.xml but it does not scroll.. Please find my code below and help me.

Detail.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#cc0031" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/small_marker" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_store_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/burger_wraps"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_detail_back"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:alpha="0.0"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_detail_basket"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_map_back"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_map_back"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:text="" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DetailActivity.java

```
  public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity{

RSSFeed feed;
int pos;
private DescAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager pager;
HorizontalScrollView hori;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    // Get the feed object and the position from the Intent
    feed = (RSSFeed) getIntent().getExtras().get("feed");
    pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");

    // Initialize the views
    adapter = new DescAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set Adapter to pager:
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    hori = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);

}



public class DescAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public DescAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feed.getItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        DetailFragment frag = new DetailFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);
        bundle.putInt("pos", position);
        frag.setArguments(bundle);

        return frag;

    }

}
```

}

detail_fragement.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/grilled" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@color/grey" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tag_price" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

DetailFragement.java

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
private int fPos;
RSSFeed fFeed;

ImageLoader imageLoader;
String Name, Price, Image_det;
HorizontalScrollView ScrollView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    fFeed = (RSSFeed) getArguments().getSerializable("feed");
    fPos = getArguments().getInt("pos");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);

    // Initializr views
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title1);

    Image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);

    Name = fFeed.getItem(fPos).getTitle();
    Price = fFeed.getItem(fPos).getPrice();
    // Set the views
    title.setText(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getTitle());
    price.setText(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getPrice());

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getImage(), Image);

    ScrollView= (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    //ScrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ScrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                return false;
            }
        });



    return view;
}
```